# AWS Kinesis stub for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm writing spec for Rails app. And need to stub request from aws kinesis services. Here is code for stub in stub_helper

```
  def stub_kinesis_client
    kinesis = Aws::Kinesis::Client.new(stub_responses: true)
    kinesis.describe_stream(stream_name: 'demo_stream')
  end
```

I got the issue:

```
NameError:
       no member 'stream_description.has_more_shards' in struct
```

It's seems has_more_shards is not exist in mock response. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the kinesis client with response to for the describe_stream method.

```
kinesis.stub_responses(:describe_stream, stream_description: {})
```

Note that this will fail because it doesn't provide any of the required attributes in the stream_description, but the exception that it raises will tell you which attributes are required.